# como crear varias cuentas de correo electronico con un dominio propio comprado en godaddy

Tags: gmail, dominio, godaddy

Si tengo un dominio en godaddy pero quiero que con ese dominio pueda crear correos electrónicos como:

- eduardo@miempresa.com  este debe apuntar al gmail de eduardo
- jesus@miempresa.com    este debe apuntar al gmail de jesus

Alguien sabe como puedo realizar este tipo de trabajos. Estuve viendo videos que se podia hacer en godaddy pero no encuentro la configuración, o conocen algún proveedor que solucione este problema? Gracias

Comment: Hasta el momento lo mejor que conozco para esto es [GSuite](https://gsuite.google.es/intl/es/) (es de pago, 4 Euros/mes por usuario) y tienen más planes para empresas. Hay más cosas aparte del correo el cual funciona con la excelente garantía de filtros y anti-spam de Gmail. Uno de los dolores de cabeza cuando se quiere tener un correo con su propio dominio es el terrible spam, los filtros anti-spam de los hosting son mediocres y tu correo se llena de correo basura. GSuite te permite manejar tu correo personal igual que Gmail, pero es tu correo personal siempre.

Comment: Estuve viendo y cobran por cada usuario :s

Comment: Sí, te lo dije en el comentario :  *es de pago, 4 Euros/mes por usuario* ... GSuite es una solución global, generalmente para empresas. Tiene muchas otras ventajas, no es solamente lo del email. Conviene que evalúes si te es rentable o no, si es sólo para el email, entonces quizá deberías pensar en otra opción, como contratar un buen filtro anti-spam y usar tus correos directamente en el hosting.

Comment: "como contratar un buen filtro anti-spam y usar tus correos directamente en el hosting" me podrias explicar mas sobre ese comentario en especial de lo correo directamente el hosting, por favor

Comment: Según mi experiencia, uno de los mayores problemas al querer usar nuestro correo personalizado, por ejemplo, `eduardo@miempresa.com` es la gran cantidad de spam que llega a ese tipo de correos cuando lo revisamos directamente en el hosting, desde alguna de las opciones que éste ofrece mediante cPanel, o si lo configuramos en un cliente local como Outlook u otros. O sea, los hostings manejan muy mal el asunto de los spams, quizá a propósito, porque luego ellos mismos te ofrecen paquetes anti-spam para evitar ese problema. Me refiero a eso, a contratar con ellos un paquete anti-spam y...

Comment: ... configurar tu correo directamente en tu cliente de correos o en Gmail, usando las credenciales que te da el hosting.  No lo he probado, no sé si funcione y también cuesta lo suyo, la diferencia es que no pagarías por cada cuenta y no contarías con las garantías de Google. Otra opción sería redirigir tu correo a otro de Gmail, ellos filtran bastante spam aún con tu correo personal con el nombre de tu dominio, pero no es lo mismo. Otra opción es usar tu correo de Gmail y poner en el reply to la dirección de tu correo personal (con el nombre del dominio)...

Comment: Ah ok, creo que ya entendi muy bien, con respecto a "Otra opción es usar tu correo de Gmail y poner en el reply to la dirección de tu correo personal (con el nombre del dominio" no tenia idea de que tambien se podria

Comment: Hay muchas opciones, debes ir probando y quedarte con la que más convenga. Por ejemplo: configurar en Gmail una cuenta POP3 o IMAP de tu correo personal (el del dominio). No se en esos casos si Gmail aplica sus filtros anti-spam al correo entrante a tu cuenta personal. Y a veces algunos hosting no permiten POP3 o IMAP, aunque creo que hoy día casi todos lo permiten.